# replace "London\\/India\\/chaina\\/" to "London_India_chaina_"

Tags: scala

I have a string `val str = "London\\/India\\/chaina\\/"` wanted to replace to `"London_India_chaina_"`

If I am doing

```
str.replaceAll("\\\/","_")
```

getting `"London\_India\_chaina\_"`

Comment: Use: `replace("/", "_")`

Answer (score 1):

Scala String is in essence java [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) object.

```
scala> val str = "London/India/chaina/"
str: String = London/India/chaina/

scala> str.replace("/", "_")
res0: String = London_India_chaina_
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one `\` character in the first parameter of `replaceAll` :

```
  object Replace {
      def main(args : Array[String]) = {
        var str = "London\\/India\\/chaina\\/"
        println(str)
        println(str.replaceAll("\\\\/","_"))
      } 
    }
```

Output :

```
London\/India\/chaina\/
London_India_chaina_
```

Answer (score 0):

Operating on the string as a sequence of characters,

```
str map {
  case '/' => '_'
  case c => c
}
```

The second case matches any other character different from `'/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val str = "London\\/India\\/chaina\\/"
str.replaceAll("""\\\\/""","_")
```